# .htaccess Same rewrite rule for another page doesn't work

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this lines in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /account.php?PAGE=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /pages.php?PAGE=$1 [L]
```

The problem is with secondary Rule, so when I want to access pages.php it jumps to account.php

What should I do?

Comment: Because both rewrite regex is same and you have an L flag too to abort looking further.

Comment: so I need to change one of the L flag? Or both?

Comment: Can you give examples of which pages should go to account and which to pages?

Comment: @Adrian, could you please do let us know from which url to which url it should redirect? Kindly do mention in your question.

Comment: As a structure? domain.com/pages.php?PAGE=something is the original structure, but I want it like that: domain.com/something

Comment: The rewriting module cannot somehow magically _guess_ what "page" actually is requested. You need to tell it in which situation it should rewrite requests to what internal object. Your current matching pattern is identical for both rules, that makes no sense. So: how is a request that should be rewritten to account.php different from a request that should be rewritten to pages.php? Once you can answer that you can implement a working rule.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Try `REQUEST_URI` with `RewriteCond`.

Comment: @arkascha the request should be the same for both pages but works for only rule of the line above.

Comment: @Adrian The request is not/can not be the same for both pages. You need to create unique rules for each request. Use the `REQUEST_URI` to check what the URI has in it. You then can direct to appropriate pages.

Comment: @user3783243 thank you for the clue but my .htaccess knowledge is so low. A more concrete example would help me a lot.

Comment: @Adrian Take a look at https://mod-rewrite-cheatsheet.com/ specifically the `Evaluate query string` part. The `!` means not so remove that bit and you can compare your values as you want. Alternatively you could send this all to a controller in PHP but that might be more work

Comment: Ask yourself this question: how should the rewriting logic decide what script to execute? Once you can give a clear answer, so a clear way how to tell apart both situations, that moment you can implement matching rules.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^account-([^/]+)$ account.php?PAGE=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pages-([^/]+)$ pages.php?PAGE=$1 [L]
```

Comment: There is no prefix. See the comment `domain.com/something` -> `domain.com/pages.php?PAGE=something` (if there were a prefix that should be first capture group then only 1 regex would be needed) Also `RewriteCond` pairs with the `RewriteRule` so the second one wouldn't be paired with anything.